# How would Elemental Affinity work with a Booming Blade-style delayed damage spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, homebrew, sorcerer

[Draconic Bloodline sorcerers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#DraconicBloodline) gain the Elemental Affinity feature at level 6:

> Starting at 6th level, **when you cast a spell that deals damage of the type associated with your draconic ancestry, you can add your Charisma modifier to one damage roll of that spell.** At the same time, you can spend 1 sorcery point to gain resistance to that damage type for 1 hour.

The description of the [*booming blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/booming-blade) spell (SCAG p. 142) states:

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon against one creature within the spell’s range, otherwise the spell fails. On a hit, the target suffers the attack’s normal effects, and it becomes sheathed in booming energy until the start of your next turn. If the target willingly moves before then, it immediately takes 1d8 thunder damage, and the spell ends.
>
> This spell’s damage increases when you reach higher levels. At 5th level, the melee attack deals an extra 1d8 thunder damage to the target, and the damage the target takes for moving increases to 2d8. Both damage rolls increase by 1d8 at 11th level and 17th level.

I realize those two can't work together normally since none of the draconic ancestry options are associated with the thunder damage type. However, let's assume we have a dragon ancestor option that lets Elemental Affinity apply to thunder damage, or a spell that works like *booming blade* but deals the damage type associated with one's Dragon Ancestor, with the same wording.

How would this hypothetical scenario work out? Above level 5 it's pretty obvious that you deal your bonus damage on impact, but below that, your initial cast only deals weapon damage - but is there anything RAW preventing you from dealing your Elemental Affinity damage on the move damage, since it's the first time this spell deals your chosen element?

(Since Elemental Affinity only applies once the character is 6th level, assume for the sake of argument that we're talking about an equivalent homebrew ability gained at an earlier level.)

Comment: Are you asking this for the purpose of developing a homebrew spell/ability of some sort? If not, can you explain the motivation a bit? Many times it helps to know why to better help you.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Ultimately yes, but that one is a bit more specific an affect, and I'd rather see if there's RAW precedent for a situation that could come up if, say, a DM gets talked into reskinning a spell as is often suggested for non-Fire draconic sorcs.

Comment: The Lore Mastery Arcane Tradition's Spell Mastery in [Unearthed Arcana](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/20170213_wizrd_wrlck_uav2_i48nf.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiz-LKplqTcAhXymeAKHU_1AZMQFjAAegQIABAB&usg=AOvVaw0CErSoU40CgATntaAvPH43) is one way these circumstances could be replicated in an actual game (albeit outside of official rules since Unearthed Arcana only contains playtest material). Would you want to ask the question with respect to this as an example, or just leave it based on this homebrew/reflavour situation.

Comment: @DavidCoffron think I'd rather keep it focused on a reflavor, since explicitly inviting UA... well, explicitly invites UA

Comment: ...Are you aware that sorcerers only gain the Elemental Affinity feature at level 6 (since you point out that the answer is clear once the character is level 5 or higher)? Or are you proposing to homebrew a similar feature that the sorcerer would get at an earlier level?

Comment: @V2Blast - I absolutely forgot about the level requirement for Elemental Affinity, yes, thank you. Let's assume this discussion is about an earlier level homebrew with the same wording.

Comment: @vonBoomslang: Alright, I've edited that information into your question now.

Comment: @V2Blast Appreciated. I'm still having difficulty wrapping my mind around the wikilike nature of this plce.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes this works

The only requirement for Elemental Affinity is that you cast a spell that deals the type associated with your draconic ancestry. If this type is thunder via a homebrew variant or Booming Blade has modified through a reflavouring or feature, it will qualify.

A spell counts as dealing the damage if the damage is a direct result of the spell's effect.

Contrast this with a spell like *shadow blade*

> You weave together threads of shadow to create a sword of solidified gloom in your hand. This magic sword lasts until the spell ends. It counts as a simple melee weapon with which you are proficient. It deals 2d8 psychic damage on a hit...

*Shadow blade* would not count as a spell that deals psychic damage since it is the weapon being created that deals the damage, rather than the spell itself.

Comment: It's also worth noting that nothing about Elemental Affinity forces you to use the bonus damage the first time that spell deals damage of that type; it only says "when you cast a spell" [that deals damage of that type]. For instance, if you're a level 5 or higher sorcerer with a fire-type dragon ancestor, and you shoot multiple Fire Bolts as part of the casting of the spell, you could choose to add the extra damage to either bolt (one of them, not both). It doesn't have to be the first bolt.

Comment: @V2Blast Fire Bolt fires a single bolt with damage going up as the caster's level does, not additional bolts. Are you thinking of Scorching Ray?

Comment: @vonBoomslang: I was! Well, initially I thought of Eldritch Blast, then realized the force damage type didn't really work for this example :P I suppose a twinned version of a single-target spell like Fire Bolt could work too.

Comment: Or you were thinking of scorching ray perhaps? Does fire damage with multiple blasts