# Does Alchemical Savant affect Elemental Weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, artificer

The Alchemist subclass of the artificer has a 5th level feature *Alchemical Savant* which states (E:RftLW, pg 58)

> Whenever you cast a spell using your alchemist's supplies as the spellcasting focus, you gain a bonus to one roll of the spell. That roll must restore hit points or be a damage roll that deals acid, fire, necrotic, or poison damage, and the bonus equals your intelligence modifier

*[Elemental Weapon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/elemental-weapon)* is an Artificer spell gives the option to grant an extra 1d4 of acid/fire damage when the enchanted weapon hits a target. Does this extra damage count as a roll of the spell and so can the roll benefit from the alchemist's intelligence modifier bonus for a single hit?

Comment: Highly related: [Does the Draconic Bloodline sorcerer's Elemental Affinity feature apply to the spell Dragon's Breath?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143407/52137), [How would Elemental Affinity work with a Booming Blade-style delayed damage spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127392/52137)

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? Am I missing anything?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Your answer seems dissimilar to the answers to the questions linked by Someone_Evil . I think the crux of the question is "what counts as the damage roll of a spell?". Without a RAW source clarifying that question I don't want to mark an answer correct. There could be a rule that is being missed or the question could be clarified by an errata later on.

Answer (score 2):

#### No, this does not work.

First, let's look at [Alchemical Savant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#Alchemist):

> At 5th level, you develop masterful command of magical chemicals, enhancing the healing and damage you create through them. Whenever you cast a spell using your alchemist’s supplies as the spellcasting focus, you gain a bonus to one roll of the spell. That roll must restore hit points or be a damage roll that deals acid, fire, necrotic, or poison damage, and the bonus equals your Intelligence modifier (minimum of +1).

This gives you a bonus to one damage roll *for the spell's damage*.

Let's look at [*elemental weapon*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/elemental-weapon):

> For the duration, *the weapon* has a +1 bonus to attack rolls and deals an extra 1d4 damage of the chosen type when it hits.

The spell *elemental weapon* does not do damage. It changes a weapon so that the weapon deals an additional 1d4 damage. This damage is *from the weapon when it hits*, not from the spell.

Therefore, the 1d4 roll is not an eligible damage roll for Alchemical Savant, since it is weapon damage, not a damage roll from the spell.

Answer (score 0):

(I've looked over the spell a couple more times, and had to change my answer)

Elemental Weapon applies a persistent effect to a non-magical weapon for its duration. Emphasis mine

> A nonmagical weapon you touch becomes a magic weapon.
> Choose one of the following damage types: acid, cold, fire, lightning, or thunder. For the duration, **the weapon has a +1 bonus to attack rolls and deals an extra 1d4 damage of the chosen type** **when it hits**.

The spell alone does not have you roll damage or healing, and so would not benefit from Alchemical Savant.